# Ionic 2 service function wait for localstorage before return

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I just learn Ionic 2 since last week, now I create a function in my service in order to return my API URL and it will checks for localstorage whether is there any token stored. If yes then it will append the token to the URL automatically, below is the code for the function:

```
getApiUrl(method: string){
    this.storage.get('user_data').then((val) => {
        let extUrl: string = null;
        if(val){
            extUrl = '?token='+val.token;
           }
        return "http://localhost/api/"+method+extUrl;
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('Your data don\'t exist and returns error in catch: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        return ''; 
    });
}
```

But then I call this function in my controller using:

```
this.http.post(this.service.getApiUrl("method_name"), data, options)
```

The following error occured:

```
Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

I had tried to change my code to use Promise but it seems not working also, how can I make my function to wait for the API URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `getApiUrl` method. You have to return the promise and call your `post` method after your `getApiUrl` promise is resolved:

```
getApiUrl(method: string){
    return this.storage.get('user_data').then((val) => {
        let extUrl: string = null;
        if(val){
            extUrl = '?token='+val.token;
           }
        return "http://localhost/api/"+method+extUrl;
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('Your data don\'t exist and returns error in catch: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        return ''; 
    });
}

this.service.getApiUrl("method_name")
  .then((url) => {
    this.http.post(url, data, options);
  });
```